# Объединение нескольких запросов mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть несколько подобных запросов:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` where `id`=1 ORDER by time DESC limit 1
SELECT * FROM `data` where `id`=2 ORDER by time DESC limit 1
..
SELECT * FROM `data` where `id`=5 ORDER by time DESC limit 1
```

Можно ли их как-то объединить в один?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `id` IN (1, 2, ..);
```

Comment: Судя по вопросу, там в in() нужно подзапрос сделать с группировкой по ид и выбрать максимальное время

Comment: именно так, для каждого id может быть разное время, требуется сделать выборку по нескольким id с максимальным временем для каждого из них

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time` DESC) rn
              FROM data
              WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 5 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f88dc13535d8773036cf8a2ce4c27765)</kbd>

Comment: можно немного прокомментировать, совсем непонятно, что написано

Comment: @user426064 Здесь написан запрос, решающий поставленную задачу. Ссылка на fiddle добавлена.

Comment: Ваш у меня так и не получился, выдает ошибку (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time` DESC) rn
' at line 1), но получилось так select * from data where (id, time) in (select id, max(time) from data group by id) order by id

Comment: @user426064 Я так понимаю, что Вы предлагаете угадать *your MariaDB server version*? хотя должны были сообщить эту информацию с самого начала...

Comment: Версия сервера: 10.0.38-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Версия протокола: 10

Comment: @user426064 Ну ёooo... седая древность... до хотя бы 10,2,2 обновиться можете?